# Mostrar resultado do loop em tempo real

Tags: php, loop, foreach

Estou a utilizar um loop para enviar emails de uma array.
Por cada vez que o loop corre a função `sleep(4);` é executada.

O problema é que o output do php apenas acontece no final, ou seja as linhas  `echo "</br>n:".$ne."&nbsp".$user["email"]."</br> >>enviado</br>";` são mostradas em output todas de uma vez e depois de todos os loops executados.

Gostaria que à medida que cada loop correr, a função echo seja exibida (uma a uma e não em de uma so vez no final).

```
foreach($users as $user) {
  $message->setTo($user["email"], $user["nome"]);
echo "\n";sleep(4);
  flush(); 
  ob_end_flush();  
  echo date('h:i:s');
  $mailer->send($message);
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

  $ne++;
  echo "</br>n:".$ne."&nbsp".$user["email"]."</br> >>enviado</br>";
```

Comment: Pergunta muito mal elaborada, explique e detalhe melhor.

Comment: penso que está claro agora ...editei a pergunta...

Comment: Esse script é executado em um navegador ou terminal?

Comment: no navegador em php

Comment: O código PHP é interpretado pelo servidor, quando o processo terminar a resposta é retornada para o navegador, por isso que aparece tudo de uma vez. Se essa pausa for necessária você vai ter que fazer esse processo via javascript/jQuery usando requisições AJAX.

Comment: ok  obrigado vou investigar como fazer isso

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior errado. Se você quiser que o resultado saida em fileiras você consegue também. Vou responder à pergunta.

Comment: Não conhecia o método citado pelo @WallaceMaxters, boa!

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior eu também pensava que não era possível fazer isso no PHP, mas depois que vi uma implementação javascript/php com Stream updates e ob_implict_flush mudei de ideia. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: E não sei se estou enganado, mas acho que por causa da ignorância de alguns esse rapaz tomou votos negativos.

Comment: O pessoal do downvote sai de fininho, como sempre :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente você está falando de `ob_implicit_flush`. Sim, é possível exibir uma saída no php mesmo durante a execução de um loop, sem esperar que esse loop tenha terminado ainda. Ou seja, os dados são impressos em pilha.

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);


foreach (range(1, 50) as $value)
{
    echo "Imprimindo {$value}";
    ob_flush();

    sleep(1);
}
```

O meu php.ini está configurado para que um buffer seja iniciado automaticamente.

Se você não sabe se o seu output buffer está automático ou não no seu php.ini, pode fazer essa pequena verificação para que tudo funcione corretamente.

```
if (ob_get_level() > 0) { 
    ob_start();
}
```

Ainda complementando a resposta, você pode fazer isso apenas utilizando a função `flush`, desde que não esteja utilizando nada relacionada ao output  buffer em seu código.

Então você pode fazer assim:

```
// Fallback para garantir que não vai ter a configuração no php.ini

while(ob_get_level() > 0) ob_end_clean();    

foreach (range(1, 50) as $value)
{
    echo "Imprimindo {$value}";
    flush();

    sleep(1);
}
```

Eu testei das duas formas e funcionou perfeitamente na minha máquina.

Comment: é...comigo nao funciona deve de ser do php.ini...

Comment: @I-amSam em um outro jeito. Combinei com o Bacco, acho que ele vai mostrar outra forma.

Comment: Hã? Eu só comentei de começar testando com apenas um `flush()` normal no loop, pra ver se resolve. Aí, só se não funcionar, fazer teste com as funções `ob_flush()` etc. Não pensei em postar resposta, pq era só isso que eu comentei mesmo.

Comment: pois eu não consegui resolver mesmo

Comment: Então tá aí seu @Bacco. Editei!

Answer (score 1):

Há diversas técnicas que podem funcionar ou não conforme o ambiente.

Aqui um exemplo ligeiramente diferente do que já foi postado:

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
ob_end_clean();

echo 'Hello World!';
flush();
ob_flush();

for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    sleep(1);
    echo PHP_EOL.'<br />'.$i;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

A única diferença é que nesse exemplo desabilitamos a compressão [zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php), a qual normalmente é ativada por padrão.

Importante também que estamos usando [ob_end_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) antes de iniciar os processos para garantir que qualquer buffer de saída já existente seja eliminado.

Não precisa ser colocado necessariamente na primeira linha dos códigos. Basta estar antes da lógica inicial do script de buffer com o qual deseja trabalhar.

Um problema que poderá ter nesse exemplo acima é que o último laço não respeita o `sleep(1)`, pois imprime logo em seguida do penúltimo. Mas esse comportamento não acontece em certos ambientes.

É muito complicado acertar algo que funcione 100%. Não há uma mágica que faça funcionar de forma consistente em todo tipo de ambiente. Tem que testar e adaptar para o seu caso específico.

Comment: obrigado, também não resultou cmg mas valeu :)